# Command-Line Question.. I recently used start atom filename.txt to open a file in atom from my command-line

Tags: command-line

However I want to open other programs in the command-line, for example I tried sublime 3 and I got an error.

My question is where do you find what is the correct spelling for the programs we desire to work within the command-line?

Answer (score 0):

The correct spelling for Sublime text is [`subl`](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/osx_command_line.html). I just googled "sublime text open from command-line".

Not all programs have command-line equivalents. For example I know Visual Studio Code installs the `code` command. But for a simpler editor like TextEdit you would need to use `open`.